# How do I characterize matricies for this linear operator on $L(\ell^{p})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

My **task** is to charakterize all real (or complex) matricies $A = (a_{ij})_{ij \in \mathbb{N}} $ which lead to the operator
\begin{align*}
A : (x_i)_i \mapsto \Big(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_{ji}x_i \Big)_j
\end{align*}

where $ A \in L(\ell^p) $ for $ p \in \{1, \infty\} $. $L(\ell^p)$ is the space of all linear and continous functions.

My **observations** on this operator are the followings:

1. $A$ simply multiplies the matrix with the sequence $(x_n)_n$ so it resembles a vector matrix multiplication.
2. For $p=1$ all series are absolutely convergent. That means no matter in which order you sum the sequence-elements, you always get the same result. And
   \begin{align*}
   \sum_{}|x_n| = \sum x_n \qquad \text{for all} \quad n \in \mathbb{N}
   \end{align*}
3. For $p=\infty$ you look at the supremum-norm.

I also got a **hint** to look at the unit-vectors. But this hint does not get me anywhere because I dont know which unit vectors are meant here. Those of $L(\ell^p)$? Or row by row inside the matrix $A$?

My **guesses** are, that $A$ has to have sequences in its columns which converge to $0$, otherwise you would sum up all elements of the sequence with a factor which could destroy the convergence and the fact that it is a operator in $L(\ell^p)$. Also $A$ is allowed to have any real or complex elements on the main-diagonal, because it only effects one element of the sequence, if only the main-diagonal of $A$ has entries $\neq 0$.

For $p=\infty$ I think it should be the same. So now im stuck with this ideas and dont know how to find a valid characterisation. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: It can be shown that for $p=1$ the norm of $A$ is equal $\sup_j\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|$ while for $p=\infty $ the norm is equal $\sup_i\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|$ For $p=1$ it suffices to analyze $A\delta_i$ where $\delta_i$ form the standard basis in $\ell^1.$ For $p=\infty $ we can apply the duality between $\ell^1$ and $\ell^\infty.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x\in \ell^1$ we have
$$\|Ax\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\left |\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j\right |\le \sum_{i=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|\,|x_j|\\
=\sum_{j=1}^\infty|x_j|\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|\le  \sup_j\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|\ \|x\|_1$$
Hence $\|A\|_{1\to 1}\le \displaystyle\sup_j\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|.$ Let $\delta_j$ denote the standard basis in $\ell^1.$ Then
$\|A\delta_j\|_1=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|$ which implies
$\|A\|_{1\to 1}\ge \displaystyle\sup_j\sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|.$

For $x\in \ell^\infty$ we get
$$\|Ax\|_\infty =\sup_i\left |\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j\right |\le \sup_i\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|\,|x_j|
\le \|x\|_\infty \sup_i\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|$$
Hence $\|A\|_{\infty\to \infty}\le \displaystyle \sup_i\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|.$ For fixed $i,$ let $x_j=\overline{a_{ij}}/|a_{ij}|$ when $a_{ij}\neq 0$  and $x_j=0,$ when $a_{ij}=0.$ Then $\|x\|_\infty \le 1$ and
$$(Ax)_i= \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}x_j=\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|$$
Thus $\|Ax\|_\infty \ge \displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|,$ which implies $\|A\|_{\infty\to \infty}\ge \displaystyle\sup_i\sum_{j=1}^\infty |a_{ij}|.$

Comment: Great! Thank you very much! Now, its interesting.. Can you tell me what the operatornorm of $A$ for $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ is?

Comment: In general if you have a linear operator $A:X\to Y,$ where $X$ and $Y$ are normed spaces then the operator norm is defined as $\|A\|=\sup_{x\neq 0}{\|Ax\|\over \|x\|}.$ Equivalently the quantity $\|A\|$ is the least constant $C$ for which $\|Ax\|\le C\|x\|.$ In your case $X=Y=\ell^p$ for $p=1$ or for $p=\infty.$

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you! That means if I try to calculate $\|A \| $ I will get $ \sup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} |a_{ij}| $? For both $p = 1$ and $p=\infty$?

Comment: No,  look carefull. The expressions for the norms $p=1 $ and $p=\infty$ are different. The roles of $i$ and $j$ are reversed.

Comment: oh gosh now I see.. Thank you very much! I got it now!